# EF5 keeps referencing property that no longer exist

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have an EF5 Model, I renamed a couple of tables and fields because they were spelled wrong.  Now when I re update the model from the DB it makes all the correct associations and entities and context all change.  But I keep getting this error below.  Mind you the field "BrowserDetailId" no longer on any table nor in Fk relationship.  I get this error only at run time, and I cant find where it thinks the FK relationship still exists.

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors:   The relationship 'PortalModel.FK_LoginActivity_LoginAttempts' was not loaded because the type 
'PortalModel.LoginAttempt' is not available.  The following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:  
The required property 'BrowserDetailId' does not exist on the type 'Portal.Entities.LoginAttempt'.      
The relationship 'PortalModel.FK_VerificationAttempts_Verification' was not loaded because the type 'PortalModel.Verification' is not available.  
The following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:  
The required property 'BroswerDetailId' does not exist on the type 'Portal.Entities.Verification'.
```

I have deleted edmx and related context and entities and recreated them, still get the error.
I have delete the FK's to the related to tables and updated the edmx model and still get the error.
I have created new edmx file and context and entites still get the error.
I have searched all the files in the solution and cant find any mention of the "BrowserDetailId".

I have been trying to figure this out for more time then i would like to admit, any help would be great.

The database is SQL Server 2008

Comment: Does it have anything to do with a typo?  I see `BrowserDetailId` and `BroswerDetailId`.

Comment: that was one of the reasons for renaming the files originally on SQL